# ruby on rails models

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I am writting social network. 
I have group's blog and user's blog, then I have group's photos and user's photos
How I must design models? all posts(photos) in one db table or in different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferable to have a single table only for photos, especially if you have multiple photos for each group or user. You could use **Single Table Inheritance** or **Polymorphic Associations** to store photos from groups and users in it. I would recommend to read some good books about the topic, [Practical Rails Social Networking Sites](http://www.apress.com/9781590598412) and [RailsSpace: Building a Social Networking Website with Ruby on Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321480791). Both are recommendable.